# Active Contours Alg

Tags: matlab

Can someone provide me with a step-by-step algorithm for implementing active contours (snakes) in matlab? the online material is very difficult for me to follow.

Comment: Please refer to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987849/active-contour-implementation/22317083#22317083

Answer (score 1):

I had had the same problem as yours
I searched for some step-by-step implementation and finally I got it
here is the link:

[Snake Implementation by MATLAB](http://www.cb.uu.se/~cris/blog/index.php/archives/217/comment-page-1#comment-2267)

I wish you success..