# Active Contour Implementation

Tags: matlab

Hi Im interested in learning active contours. I have searched online for some code to understand but it seems they examples are specific to an application. Can anyone provide a link or example with simple implementation of it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if it's too late. I looked up Matlab Exchange when I knew pretty much nothing about active contours and found the code in the link below quite helpful:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28149-snake-active-contour

There are a lot of comments in the code that explain what each option does, and if you look at the papers referenced (which I strongly recommend you should do) you will be able to adjust those options to suit the needs of your project. There are some simple examples there as well.

I have only used the 2D version, so I cannot comment on the effectiveness of the 3D version. I found the 2D version an easy introduction to active contour algorithms.

A word of warning, the interp2 function called in the code is slow, you may want to replace it with a faster option.

Answer (score 1):

There are two active contour models: Parametric deformable models and Geometric deformable models. I was worked on parametric deformable models and want to introduce you a great code:

Code of Parametric deformable model:

[iacl.ece.jhu.edu/Projects/gvf/](http://iacl.ece.jhu.edu/Projects/gvf/)

Which is written by Xu, who is the author of GVF. He finished traditional active models, balloon models, distance map and GVF in his code.